# Landsat Collection 1 to Collection 2 migration

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-surface-temperature

2

I want to create the LST in GEE for my region. How do I fix the Land surface temperature error in the light of 'Landsat Collection 1 to Collection 2 migration'? I am receiving minLST: 4583.687; maxLST: 5434.138 which is unrealistic.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/496f252dd01bed85c1e3ca749b08538f

```
Map.setCenter(42.0811, 17.6421)

var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
 .filterBounds(geometry)
 .filterDate('2021-04-01','2021-07-31')
 .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 5);
Map.addLayer(image);
print(image);

var applyScaleFactors = function (image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('B.*').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('B10').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
    .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
};

var srColScaled = image.map(applyScaleFactors);


//vis params
var vizParams = {
bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B4'],
min: 0,
max: 4000,
gamma: [1, 0.9, 1.1]
};

var vizParams2 = {
bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
min: 0,
max: 3000,
gamma: 1.4,
};


//load landsat 8 sr image
{
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2/LC08_167048_20210709').clip(geometry);
print(image, 'image');
Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);
}


//median (ndvi) 
{
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 
'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
print(ndvi,'ndvi');
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'ndvi');
}

//select thermal band 10(with brightness tempereature), no calculation 
var thermal= image.select('ST_B10').multiply(0.1);
var b10Params = {min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(thermal, b10Params, 'thermal');

// find the min and max of NDVI
{
var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min');

var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max')
}


// Fraction of Vegetation (Fv) Calculation
// Formula: ((NDVI - NDVI_min) / (NDVI_max - NDVI_min))^2

// Calculate the Fraction of Vegetation (Fv) using the NDVI values within the specified range.
// NDVI_min represents the minimum NDVI value, and NDVI_max represents the maximum NDVI value
var fv = ((ndvi.subtract(min)).divide(max.subtract(min)))
          .pow(ee.Number(2))
          .rename('FV');


// Emissivity Calculation
// Formula: 0.004 * FV + 0.986

// Calculate Land Surface Emissivity (EM) using the Fraction of Vegetation (FV).
// The 0.004 coefficient represents the emissivity variation due to vegetation,
// and the 0.986 represents the base emissivity for other surfaces.

var EM = fv.multiply(ee.Number(0.004)).add(ee.Number(0.986)).rename('EMM');

// Now, lets calculate the land surface temperature (LST)

// Formula: (TB / (1 + (λ * (TB / 1.438)) * ln(em))) - 273.15

var LST = thermal.expression(
  '(Tb / (1 + (0.00115 * (Tb / 1.438)) * log(EMM))) - 273.15', {
    'Tb': thermal.select('ST_B10'), 
    // Select the thermal band (Tb)
    'EMM': EM // Assign emissivity (EMM)
  }).rename('LST Shuqaiq Power Plant');

// Add the LST Layer to the Map with Custom Visualization Parameters
Map.addLayer(LST, {
  min: 18.47, // Minimum LST value
  max: 42.86, // Maximum LST value
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ]}, 'LST');


//min max LST
{
var min = ee.Number(LST.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),

scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'minLST');

var max = ee.Number(LST.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),

scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'maxLST');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model. This is an example of a "Wall of code" post, which lacks any useful information in the Question body. You can probably counter the downvotes by transferring the current title text to the top of the code block, then add another paragraph to give more background information on your task, then add a question, and *then* write a title which summarizes the subject of the Question (as a brief statement).

Comment: Hi Vince. I thoroughly edited my question. Hope this time will be uploaded for response.

Comment: You missed the part about having information in the Question body. The title should ***not*** be the only place with English text. In fact, the title should only be a brief summary of the topic of the Question.

Comment: Vince. Hope I did what you asked for?